# convert VARCHAR2 data to date in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have the following data in `TIMESTAMP` column

```
TIMESTAMP - VARCHAR2

Format - YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss.0

2018-01-31 23:47:35.0
2018-01-01 00:00:48.0
2018-01-01 06:54:36.0
```

I'm trying to make a query to get data between two dates `(example 4th Jan to 18th Jan)` but im not sure how can i convert this into `DATE` format. Previously i used to get the data everyday and used `WHERE TIMESTAMP LIKE '2018-01-04%'` in my sql query.

Really appreciate if someone could assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `to_date()`:

```
where to_date(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.F') >= date '2018-01-04' and
      to_date(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.F') < date '2018-01-09'
```

However, you are using a good date format, so you can use string comparisons:

```
where timestamp >= '2018-01-04' and
      timestamp  < '2018-01-09'
```

Although this is convenient, you should be storing the value as a date or timestamp.  Storing date/time values as strings is generally bad (although your format makes this more reasonable).

Comment: Also - don't name columns timestamp!

Comment: @bobdylan please may i know if there will be any issues regarding this?